# How to deal with non-working key on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I've problem with my Macbook Pro (with *El Captain* installed on it) where one of the keys (such as <kbd>r</kbd>) doesn't work at all, so each time when I'm typing a word with "r", I've to keep pasting it from the system clipboard. It's very inconvenient.

I'm planning to see Genius Bar, but since then, I'd like to find a better way to deal with such problem.

I've also consider external keyboard, but it's another inconvenience, where you have to carry it physically with you.

Is there any way of rebinding a keyboard key into another one (like <kbd>r</kbd> into <kbd>§</kbd>)? Or do can you suggest something better?

Comment: Take a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219629/how-can-i-rebind-keyboard-keys-in-os-x.

Comment: The two apps used to fix things like this are Ukelele and Karabiner.  Also you could just create a shortcut in system prefs/keyboard/text, but would be more cumbersome probably.

Comment: In prefs/keyboard/text I can only replace pattens for the whole words, not single keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments and in this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/219629/22781), using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) app should work with the following configuration of [`private.xml` file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) (edit in *Misc* tab):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Use § to type R</name>
    <identifier>private.replace_r_key</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DANISH_DOLLAR, KeyCode::R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

and enable newly created item after reloading the file in *Change Key* tab.

To find out the right key code, use *EventViewer* in *Misc* tab.